# PHPMailer won´t send emails

Tags: php, phpmailer

I´m working on netbeans, on winsows and with xampp. I believe it has something to do with the version of PHPMailer, I see examples with

> PHPAutoload.php

but with the version I downloaded from gitHub I don´t see that file. Everything look fine, it does insert into the data base but got to this part of the code

`$msg = "Something wrong happened! Please try again!";`

I pasted the PHPMailer folder into c:/xampp/htdocs/pojectmail/PHPMailer.

Here is my register.php code

```
    <?php
    $msg = "";
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
        use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'research_phpEmailConfirmation');

        $name = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
        $email = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $password = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $cPassword = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['cPassword']);

        if ($name == "" || $email == "" || $password != $cPassword)
            $msg = "Please check your inputs!";
        else {
            $sql = $con->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
            if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {
                $msg = "Email already exists in the database!";
            } else {
                $token = 'qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnmQWERTZUIOPASDFGHJKLYXCVBNM0123456789!$/()*';
                $token = str_shuffle($token);
                $token = substr($token, 0, 10);

                $hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

                $con->query("INSERT INTO users (name,email,password,isEmailConfirmed,token)
                    VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$hashedPassword', '0', '$token');
                ");

                include_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
                include_once "PHPMailer/Exception.php";

                $mail = new PHPMailer();
                $mail->setFrom('hello@codingpassiveincome.com');
                $mail->addAddress($email, $name);
                $mail->Subject = "Please verify email!";
                $mail->isHTML(true);
                $mail->Body = "aa";

                if ($mail->send()) {
                $msg = "You have been registered! Please verify your email!";
            } else {
                $msg = "Something wrong happened! Please try again!";
            }
        }
        }
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Register</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 100px;">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" align="center">

                <img src="images/logo.png"><br><br>

                <?php if ($msg != "") echo $msg . "<br><br>" ?>

                <form method="post" action="register.php">
                    <input class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name..."><br>
                    <input class="form-control" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email..."><br>
                    <input class="form-control" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password..."><br>
                    <input class="form-control" name="cPassword" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password..."><br>
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code have multiple errors, you did not copy this from github...
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer use their example

Comment: can you help me with the erros you say I have? and what I meant is that I downloaded the PHPMailer folder from github the same link you are sharing I also tried their example and didn't work for me

Comment: `PHPMailerAutoload.php` is indeed obsolete and does not apply to the current version; use composer instead. You need to define "didn't work" and "won't send". Read the troubleshooting guide.

Comment: I did and it worked thanks @Synchro